# Scala typed Traits and type matching

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, lift

I am currently working on a E-Commerce application in scala / lift and cannot figure out how to match correctly on my type hierarchy. my current implementation is:

```
abstract trait BaseProduct[T <: BaseProduct[T]] extends MongoRecord[T] with ObjectIdPk[T] {
  self:T =>
  def whatever
  ...
}

abstract trait SimpleType[T <: BaseProduct[T]] extends BaseProduct[T] {
  self:T =>
  val producttype = "product/simple"
}

abstract trait ConfigurableType[T <: BaseProduct[T],E <: SimpleType[E]] extends BaseProduct[T] {
  self: T =>
  val producttype = "product/configurable"
}

class ClothingProduct extends SimpleType[ClothingProduct] {
  def meta = ClothingProduct
}

class ConfigurableClothing extends ConfigurableType[ConfigurableClothing,ClothingProduct] {
  val childmeta = ClothingProduct
  val configurableFields = List(color,size)
  def meta = ConfigurableClothing
}
```

With this in place I want to implement a Shopping Cart which should only take Products of  Type SimpleType (and BaseProduct). It should also implement a function that takes any kind of BaseProduct with a pattern matching clause that should react to wheater it is a Simple or a Configurable Type.

My first implementations which drives me crazy due to Type Errors was:

```
object Cart extends SessionVar[List[CartItem]](List()) {
  def addProduct(product:SimpleType[_],quantity:Int = 1) = {
    this.get.partition(_.product.id.is == product.id.is) match {
      case (Nil,xs) => this.set(CartItem(product,quantity) :: xs)
      case (x,xs) => this.set(CartItem(product,x.head.quantity + quantity) :: xs)
    }
  }
}

case class CartItem(product:SimpleType[_], quantity:Int)  {
  def lineTotal:Double = quantity * product.price.is
}
```

With to following function to add a Cart Item:

```
def addBasketLink(prod:BaseProduct[_]) = {
prod match {
  case x:SimpleType[_] => Cart.addProduct(x)
  case _ => S.notice("Sorry not possible to add to Basket")
}
```

My main issue is that "Underscore" definition of the supplied type to SimpleType which causes type violation errors. I am currently not able to figure out how to do the wanted typing right. It would be great it someone could tell me where my error is and properbly explain to me how I work with typed traits correctly.

Thanks

Comment: In which line does the problem occurs?

Comment: If you have solved your problem by now, feel free to post a solution yourself (and accept it).